# Battling with localization of MSI installer using Wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to set up my MSI installer developed with Wix to support multi-language UI, so I created `Strings_en-us.wxl` file to contain this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
  <String Id="Language">1033</String>
  <String Id="Codepage">1252</String>
  <String Id="DowngradeErrorMessage">A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed.</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

And then from within `Product.wxs` file:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="$(var.ProduceCode)"
           Name="TestSetupProject1"
           Version="$(var.Version)"
           Language="!(loc.Language)" 
           Codepage="!(loc.Codepage)"
           Manufacturer="$(var.CompanyName)" 
           UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
```

I immediately get an error:

> error CNDL0276: The code page '!(loc.Codepage)' is not a valid Windows
>   code page. Please check the Product/@Codepage attribute value in your
>   source file.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the lack of any replies I will conclude that this is not possible.

I'm not sure if it's Microsoft's fault or some omission in the Wix parser? The only way to do this is to hard-code the code page number right into the .wxs file itself, which is terribly inconvenient, since it will have to be switched to an appropriate code page number when recompiling for a different language. And apart from that, who is using code pages these days anyway?

PS. In hopes of fixing it once and for all, I tried doing this (like it should've been done from the get-go):

```
Codepage="UTF-8"
```

It compiled but the resulting MSI file's UI looked like this :)

[image]

Comment: I'm not experienced in this area but... Windows Installer uses codepages for summary information and strings. They have different usages and restrictions. You can't put any of the Unicode codepage ids in Product/@Codepage. These links might help: [Creating a Database with a Neutral Code Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368057.aspx) [WiX Code Pages](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/codepage.htm) [Summary Information Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372044.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The extension element [`WixLocalization`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wixloc/wixlocalization.html) has an attribute `@Codepage` that overrides the one specified `Product/@Codepage`. From the linked page:

> The code page integer value or web name for the resulting database. You can also specify -1 which will not reset the database code page.

Also relevant, if not directly mentioned in the question, there are two different places that localized strings appear in the final MSI: in the summary information stream and in the installer database proper. See [MSI Databases and Code Pages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2005/10/05/477577.aspx) for more information. The code page for the SIS is specified by the attribute `Package/@SummaryCodepage`, in which you can use a `!(loc)` variable.